# Node can't sync with the mainnet

Tags: nodeos, mainnet, node, full-node

my node has not been able to synchronize with the mainnet for a couple of months. A few weeks ago, synchronization was on ~95% but dropped to 93% in 2 weeks. Receiving new blocks in the mainnet faster than I synchronize with my node.

I don't know what I can do to up-to-date my node.

- Head block number on my node:  `45451812`
- Head block number on mainnet node: `48645197`

Server:

- 4 vCPU (htop says that the load is about 3%)
- 16 Gb of RAM (12gb used)
- 500 Gb EBS type SSD with 3000iops max (but uses 1650)
- Download: 803.79 Mbit/s
- Upload: 900.72 Mbit/s

List of peers:

```
    "peer": "peer.eosn.io:9876",
    "peer": "bp.antpool.com:443",
    "peer": "fullnode.eoslaomao.com:443",
    "peer": "mars.fnp2p.eosbixin.com:443",
    "peer": "peer.main.alohaeos.com:9876",
    "peer": "peering.mainnet.eoscanada.com:9876",
    "peer": "publicnode.cypherglass.com:9876",
    "peer": "p2p.genereos.io:9876",
    "peer": "seed1.greymass.com:9876",
    "peer": "node1.eosnewyork.io:6987",
    "peer": "bp.cryptolions.io:9876",
    "peer": "eos.nodepacific.com:9876",
    "peer": "peer.eosjrr.io:9876",
    "peer": "p2p.eosdetroit.io:3018",
    "peer": "p2p.unlimitedeos.com:15555",
    "peer": "peer2.mainnet.helloeos.com.cn:80",
    "peer": "185.253.188.1:19876",
    "peer": "peer1.mainnet.helloeos.com.cn:80",
    "peer": "pub0.eosys.io:6637",
    "peer": "mainnet.eoscalgary.io:5222",
    "peer": "node.eosflare.io:1883",
    "peer": "p2p.eosio.cr:1976",
    "peer": "node1.eoscannon.io:59876",
    "peer": "mainnet.eospay.host:19876",
    "peer": "seed2.greymass.com:9876",
    "peer": "node2.eosnewyork.io:6987",
    "peer": "pub1.eosys.io:6637",
    "peer": "807534da.eosnodeone.io:19872",
    "peer": "eos-seed-de.privex.io:9876",
    "peer": "p2p.meet.one:9876",
```

Comment: did you restart nodeos? Also what version are you using? 1.6.3 should be best as of right now.